# Angular material Scrollbar issue

Tags: angular-material, angular7

[image]

Link:- https://stackblitz.com/angular/qmedkbvramy?file=app%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.ts

I am trying angular material scollbar look as in the attached picture. But I can't figure out, how to do this.

Comment: I don't think material provides a native way to style this one, you need to use css to achieve the desire result.

Comment: Thanks, Can you help me with desired css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material by default doesn't provide any styles to change the scrolling

You can use this css to change the scrollbar style

```
cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #555;
}
```

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkw9ac

Comment: Thanks,  one issue is there- list is going up but corresponding scroll is not moving as the list goes up. Its kinda bug or something.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr not a bug but, as many items are there it moves slowly

Comment: @Justcode did you notice the flashing issue on scroll? 
when we override scrollbar styles, it's not flashing on scrolling.but it seems the performance is different. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @NaeimFard I did not, Can you explain more?

Comment: @Justcode https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkw9ac-dpnnaw  
drag scroll thumb by mouse to see the difference

Comment: @Justcode posted as a question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62811427/angular-virtual-scroll-performance-issue-on-overriding-scrollbar-styles

Comment: Which browser are you using? I used chrome works fine