# Angular Virtual scroll performance issue on overriding scrollbar styles

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, virtualscroll, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I'm using `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` to apply virtual scrolling. Unfortunately, after applying styles to the scrollbar, scrolling is not smooth anymore. The native (right side) scrollbar is flashing but it's moving smoother. Tested on Chrome.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkw9ac-dpnnaw

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was a chrome related issue. In the newer version, both of them are rendering perfectly.